# list comprehension even list elements instead of loop and how to refer only to the index

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to use list comp' instead of a loop.
Let's sat I have a list of lists and I want only the even index elements.
Eg: [[a,a], [b,b], [c,c],[g,g]] to..... [[a,a], [c,c]]

This doesn't work

```
a = [i for i in the_list if i % 2 == 0)]
```

Comment: You have to iterate over the index, not the element in itself, use `enumerate`. Or just take a slice `l[::2]`

Comment: Even or odd? Your example is keeping only the odd ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution that keeps only lists with even indexes:

```
result = [lst for i, lst in enumerate(the_list) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Oh great. Thought I missed the index number. Thank you!